# what is the best way to do bidirectional IPC between a long-running c process and python?

Tags: python, c, ipc, protocol-buffers, thrift

I have an existing C process that can take one text input and produce a single image file.
This C process has a high setup/teardown cost due to it's interface with an external system.
Once the setup/teardown has occured the actual production of image from text is almost instantaneous.

My plan is to daemonize the C process, so it will receive text and produce image files in an infinite loop, while maintaining a connection to the external system.

I will also write a small client program in python, which will interface with the daemon to send text/receive the image.

The target OS is unix.

The question is, what is the best way to do bidirectional IPC between python/C in this case?
Should I just open a unix domain socket and send packed structs back and forth, or should I look at something like Apache Thrift or protobuf?

UPDATE:

Just going to keep it simple, and open a unix domain socket

Comment: I would go for the simplest solution that does the job.  Probably a pair of named pipes at some well-known location in the file system is the least hassle.  You will only have to deal with standard file commands.

Comment: yeah you should have made this answer so i could accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sockets are the way to go here I think. On Unix, I would recommend the `AF_UNIX` sockets (see `unix(7)` manpage). Those are easily created in both C++ and python (`sockets` module). This avoids problems with port collisions or rights to open ports on the local system.

Unix sockets perform reasonably well and can easily be exchanged for `AF_INET6` sockets if you decide to work with remote workers.

For packing/unpacking the data, the `struct` module using the [compiled `Struct` objects](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#classes) seems reasonable for me. Thats how I have done it in the past and the performance was quite good (no measurements taken, as it was too good for me to investigate).

Comment: +1, though I don't think stdin/stdout pipes are viable for a daemon process which a Python client connects to after it was started.

Comment: Yes, I agree using Unix domain sockets have many advantages.

I agree with Sven and I don't think your statement about pipes makes sense either.

Also, you didn't touch at all on the method for transporting the data over the socket once it's opened (i mentioned packed structs , using the `struct` module)

Comment: @python_noob okay, I didn't read it like that the C process will be always in the background and not started deamonized by the Python process. In that case, pipes are nonsense ofc. `struct` is fine for me, which is why I didn't mention it explicitly, I'll correct that in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

My default choice would be to use normal sockets communicating over localhost. Sockets are a well understood language and platform neutral API that tend to perform very well. They also the advantage of not tieing you to two processes on the same box which can be advantageous in many situations.

Comment: I know that this is common, but my experience is that this has very bad results. It leads to security problems in code that should never be network accessible, both in terms of accidentally letting the outside world talk to your program and letting untrusted users talk to it. It also suffers from namespacing problems, as you might pick the same port number as someone else. And finally, using port numbers, rather than sane paths, is just awkward.